# Django - Can't load static file (404 error)

Tags: django

I'm developing web with django framework.

So I have 3 folders in my static file like this.

```
*web
  *home
  *static
    *admin
    *scripts
    *styles
  *web
  *manage.py
  *db.sqlite3
```

and I have my setting file with this static setup

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)
```

But when I type python3 manage.py collectstaitc I  get this result

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/pwanhsu/django/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 349, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/pwanhsu/django/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 341, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/pwanhsu/django/django/core/management/base.py", line 290, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/pwanhsu/django/django/core/management/base.py", line 341, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/pwanhsu/django/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 176, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/Users/pwanhsu/django/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 98, in collect
    for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
  File "/Users/pwanhsu/django/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 112, in list
    for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
  File "/Users/pwanhsu/django/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 28, in get_files
    directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
  File "/Users/pwanhsu/django/django/core/files/storage.py", line 286, in listdir
    for entry in os.listdir(path):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/pwanhsu/Desktop/v_bridge/web/web/static'
```

I can successfuly collect static file if I remove the STATICFILES_DIRS like this

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

0 static files copied to '/Users/pwanhsu/Desktop/v_bridge/web/static', 56 unmodified.
```

In my html file, I have these codes

{% load staticfiles %}

But the server return me an 404 error

```
[08/Sep/2016 03:36:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5831
[08/Sep/2016 03:36:45] "GET /static/scripts/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1763
[08/Sep/2016 03:36:45] "GET /static/scripts/icons/social/stylesheets/social_foundicons.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1775
[08/Sep/2016 03:36:45] "GET /static/scripts/icons/general/stylesheets/general_foundicons.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1781
```

Anyone has idea about how to set up the static path or what I did wrong. Really confuse with it.

Answer (score 1):

Use
    STATICFILES_DIRS=('. /static',)
or

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static' ), )
```

Comment: That one helped me. Was following a tutorial that has mentioned variable name incorrect all along i.e. "STATIC_FILES_DIRS". Strange that keeping the debugging True didn't point out this error, instead it kept giving 404 error for not being able to find the static file.

Answer (score 1):

Your `settings.py` is in `web/web/` directory. You `static` dir is in `web/` directory. In this case set:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'static))
```

[STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) defines the additional locations the staticfiles. You don't need this settings.

Comment: The server return me this "The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use BASE_DIR in staticfiles_dir:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

or

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'web/static')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
STATIC_ROOT='static'
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
  os.path.join(SITE_ROOT ,'/static/'),
]
```

This is actually snippet from one of my projects.In the begining ,I have struggled with static files too.This should fix your problem.If you are still getting 404.Check the permissions on static files dir and static files